# Horizontal spacing in caption in algorithm2e

Tags: spacing, margins, algorithm2e

In `algorithm2e`, how can I shift the caption to the left? There is a small space that I need to remove.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
Initialize 
\\ 
Do stuff ...
\caption{Example sdfkjdshf ksdjhf dskjfhssdkjfhds kfsjh 1kjh kjh kjh d}
\label{alg:example}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**
Even if there is space for some characters, the caption goes on a new line. Why? How can I fix that?

Comment: Don't mix the use of [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) with [`algpseudocode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). One *or* the other.

Comment: Why is it a problem? It does not give me any error and I use it for `\Call`.

Comment: You can write your own `algorithm2e`-like `\Call`. They each handle the display of content differently.

Comment: Ok, did not know that there can be conflicts. Fixed :)

Comment: You need an inner loop without an outer one, this is illogical. I know of no language in which you can work in inner loop skipping the outer one.

Comment: @AboAmmar Indeed, I made a mistake. Sorry for the silly question, I am too tired to have noticed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\SetAlCapHSkip{0em}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
Initialize 
\\ 
Do stuff ...
\parbox{\linewidth}{\caption{Example caption long enough caption to see how it wraps at page borders.}}
\label{alg:example}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

You can add the command `\SetAlCapHSkip{<length>}` to control that space before the caption. Here, I just reset it to zero by `\SetAlCapHSkip{0em}`. You can choose whatever value you feel nice.

In case you need to adjust the indentation of the numbers also, you can use the command `\DecMargin{<length>}` to decrease their margin by the value `<length>`.

**Update**

The `caption` package is not actually necessary here. For your edited part of the question, you can solve the width issue by using a `\parbox` (of width equal to the total `\linewidth`) for the caption as follows:

```
\parbox{\linewidth}{\caption{<...>}}
```

Comment: Many thanks! But what if cannot use the `caption` package?

Comment: And I also added a new small question. I would really appreciate if you can help me :)

Comment: @Simon Please see my update.